# How to groupby and calculate new field with python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'd like to group by a specific column within a data frame called 'Fruit' and calculate the percentage of that particular fruit that are 'Good'

See below for my initial dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': ['Apple','Apple','Banana'], 'Condition': ['Good','Bad','Good']})
```

Dataframe

```
    Fruit   Condition
0   Apple   Good
1   Apple   Bad
2   Banana  Good
```

See below for my desired output data frame

```
    Fruit   Percentage
0   Apple   50%
1   Banana  100%
```

Note: Because there is 1 "Good" Apple and 1 "Bad" Apple, the percentage of Good Apples is 50%.

See below for my attempt which is overwriting all the columns

```
groupedDF = df.groupby('Fruit')
groupedDF.apply(lambda x: x[(x['Condition'] == 'Good')].count()/x.count())
```

See below for resulting table, which seems to calculate percentage but within existing columns instead of new column:

```
        Fruit Condition
Fruit       
Apple   0.5 0.5
Banana  1.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can compare `Condition` with [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and take advantage of the fact that `True` is (1) and `False` is (0) when processed as numbers and take the [`groupby mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) over `Fruits`:

```
new_df = (
    df['Condition'].eq('Good').groupby(df['Fruit']).mean().reset_index()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
    Fruit  Condition
0   Apple        0.5
1  Banana        1.0
```

We can further [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to a format string and [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) to get output into the shown desired output:

```
new_df = (
    df['Condition'].eq('Good')
        .groupby(df['Fruit']).mean()
        .map('{:.0%}'.format)  # Change to Percent Format
        .rename('Percentage')  # Rename Column to Percentage
        .reset_index()  # Restore RangeIndex and make Fruit a Column
)
```

`new_df`:

```
    Fruit Percentage
0   Apple        50%
1  Banana       100%
```

*Naturally further manipulations can be done as well.